# How to mail the table layout in Android

Tags: android

I know how to send a simple text mail using intent but I have a dynamically populated table layout which I want to mail. How do I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience android's email client ignores html table formatting. You will have to implement [your own email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app/2033124#2033124).

Refer to this table to check android [email html capabilities](http://www.dialogue1.de/en/android_email-clients_overview.html)

Comment: But table layout is there in the list....Just tell me how to refer to the layout...so that I can pass it via intent.